# IOS Json error in sending to http post and setting entity

Tags: ios, json, post

Hi  I am sending an http post request to a server the java code i am referring to has a method as set entity in the post request. How can i achieve this in iOS .

I am presently putting the json data to be sent in the body but am getting the error

> Error 500 Cannot read request parameters due Invalid parameter, expected to be a pair

but was

```
{
  "chatMessage" : {
    "reportRequest" : "Sent",
    "text" : "wdfsds acd"
}
```

my code is

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[var.projectUsername base64EncodedString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
   NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:messageText.text,@"text",@"Sent",@"reportRequest",nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionary,@"chatMessage", nil];
     NSError *error = nil;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary1  options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];



[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Comment: how can i send the above json as a pair the Json formed is correct but is still not being accepted

Comment: The JSON you have written in your question is not correct. It is missing "}" at the end.

Comment: probably i missed copying that but rest assured its there

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your code:- 
`[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: Hi Piyush , 
This still dosent work i  have it as default and in java I'm setting entity in the post request and getting the values but can't get a work around in iOS

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: before  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

Comment: infact i get a 401 instead of 500

Comment: Error 500 is different from error 401. Error 401 is due to unauthorized access.

Comment: Yup i Agree but thats not the problem I'm getting 
The Json I'm sending is giving an error and is expecting a pair which I'm unable to send

Comment: I'm able to achieve this in android by post request.setentity(requestData); where requestData is the Json object  . I don't know an alternative for set entity in ios

Comment: ok. Try this. Replace NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary1  options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]; with NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:nil  options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)0 error:&error];

Comment: For options in NSJSONSerialization, try (NSJSONWritingOptions)0 or 0.

Comment: Still the same if options:0 
<title>Error 500 Cannot read request parameters due Invalid parameter, expected to be a pair but was {"chatMessage":{"reportRequest":"Sent","text":"fgdhdfhdfhfgh"}}<

Comment: Are you sure parameter used at client side have same spelling as of server side. Because parameters are case-sensitive in http post.

Comment: Spelling of parameter "chatMessage" must be same on both client & server.

Comment: ok the only difference i can find is that in the android its join like this {
    "chatMessage":
    {"text":"hey",
    "reportRequest":"Sent"}}

and in iOS its {"chatMessage":{
    "reportRequest" : "Sent",
    "text":"hey"}} The Difference lies in order

Comment: Tried sending hard coded data but still failed also searched a lot and found that an entity in java has its own header i think ,and it's not there in iOS  